# How to disable dropdown in Windows Phone?

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-7

I am developing a web app, in Windows phone alone `disabled` attribute for disabling the drop down is not working i.e, for the code below, I used disabled attribute, but i am able to change the drop down values only in windows phone, in other phones/browsers, it is working correctly.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My HTML File</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="">
            <select  disabled="disabled">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Select an option</option>
                <option value="1">Value 1</option>
                <option value="2">Value 2</option>
                <option value="3">Value 3</option>
                <option value="4">Value 4</option>
                <option value="5">Value 5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right. I have tested on my Windows Phone 7 and it is not working. But I have tested by disabling individual elements (`<option>`) and it works.

Comment: ya well said,  it is disabled by using disabled attribute for individual options, but those options are visible when we click the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select disabled>
```

is a boolean, so its presence means the select is disabled. If the attribute isn't there then select will be enabled.

Comment: I am able to select in windows phone that is the issue i am facing.

Comment: And if you have it as just
`<select disabled>`
rather than
`<select disable="disabled">`
does it still not work as expected?

Comment: I Tried both with equal to and without options, both are not working, see rubenfa answer and my comment.